# Not delete params in URL, when sorting [ RAILS 3 ]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorting, filter, get, parameters

I have sortable table columns, made like that http://asciicasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns
And I have simply filter options for two columns in table, made at select_tag (GET method).

This two function don't work together. When I change filter, the sort parameter disappear and inversely.

```
<th><%= sortable "Id" %></th>
<th>
  Status<br/>
  <form method="get">
  <%= select_tag(:status, options_for_select([['All', 'all']]+@statuses, params[:status]),{:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'}) %> 
</th>
<th><%= sortable "Operation" %></th>
<th>
  Processor<br/>
  <%= select_tag(:processor, options_for_select([['All', 'all']]+@processor_names, params[:processor]),{:onchange => 'this.form.submit()'}) %>
  </form> 
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

hehe, trivial solution

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)  
  title ||= column.titleize  
  css_class = (column == sort_column) ? "current #{sort_direction}" : nil  
  direction = (column == sort_column && sort_direction == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"  
  link_to title, {:status => params[:status], :processor => params[:processor], :sort => column, :direction => direction}, {:class => css_class}
```

end

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Kamil works fine for a single controller.
[Episode 228](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns) puts sortable method inside application_helper so if you want use it in other controllers you must add all the params.
You can solve with *params.merge*

```
link_to title, params.merge(:sort => column, :direction => direction), {:class => css_class}
```